# With JQuery Validate, remote error is not displayed and form submit button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two problems with the Jquery validate.

1) The required error message is displayed well, but the remote error message is not displayed. I have checked the server response (false/true) with the F12/Network tab in the Chrome.

2) The form submit button is not working at all.
(But it is working if I remove all the script code.)

Here is my code:

```
<style>
    input.error, textarea.error {border:1px solid red;}
    label.error {display:block; color:red; margin-top:15px;}
</style>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
        },
        rules: {
            inputNickname: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "signup_check.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        inputNickname: function() {
                            return $("#inputNickname").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        messages : {
            inputNickname: {
                required: "Please enter the nickname.",
                remote: "The nickname is already in use."
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('submit check');
            form.submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="signupForm" action="signup_ok.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Sign up</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="inputNickname">Nickname</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputNickname" type="text" name="inputNickname">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to cancel?')" href="javascript:history.back(-1)">Cancle</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I don't know why and what's wrong...

Comment: As far as I am aware, for `inputNickname` validation, `inputNickname.val()` will be sent automatically to the remote checker. You only need to specify `data: {...}` for *additional* fields to be sent alongside the one being validated (ie `inputNickname`). If I had to guess, sending `inputNickname` in the `data` shouldn't do any harm but you might try omitting `data`completely and see what happens.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 // Thanks, but nothing has changed...

Comment: 'Twas a longshot. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905164/3478010) suggests you are doing everything correctly but give it a read and see if you can spot some difference.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 // Thanks again. Actually, if I comment out the code of the remote line, other validation rules and the form submit button are working, so I also think something's wrong in that part, but I have no idea what it is, because I can see the server response correctly with the Chrome as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the problem. The problem was `<meta charset="utf-8">`.
I still don't understand why but changing from the `<meta charset="utf-8">` to `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` fixed it. It's now working with no issues.